# How to Implement a User-Input Theme

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, themes

I am playing around with theme. I am wanting to let the user choose which theme they would prefer. The user login screen contains a dropdown menu inside an outlined textfield where they can choose a color from a predefined list. The color that they choose is then saved in a mutableStateFlow variable in the view model. To implement the change, I am pulling the variable into my mainactivity and passing it as a parameter to the app's theme composable. Inside of the theme I have a 'when' statement that takes the theme parameter and, based on that, chooses the theme color palette. However, this implementation is not working. I have tried many ways, including putting the variable in a data class, using the darktheme boolean as the theme's parameter instead of the color name, using if/else statements instead of the 'when', etc. I just can't seem to make it work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    // Initial call to navHost
    lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    var viewModel = DropDownMenuViewModel()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val theme by viewModel.userThemeFlow.collectAsState()
            DropDownMenuTheme(theme = theme) {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    navController = rememberNavController()
                    SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class DropDownMenuViewModel: ViewModel() {

    // Captures state for user names
    private var _userName = mutableStateListOf<UserNameUiState>()

   // Returns list of user names
    fun getUserNameList(): List<UserNameUiState> {
        return _userName
    }

    // Takes the user name input and adds it to the user name list
    fun addUserName(name: UserNameUiState) {
        _userName.add(name)
    }

    // Captures parent entered theme
    var _userTheme = MutableStateFlow<String>("")
    val userThemeFlow: StateFlow<String> get() = _userTheme

    fun setUserTheme(theme: String) {
        _userTheme.value = theme
    }
}
```

User Login Screen:

```
@Composable
fun UserSignUpScreen(
navController: NavController,
viewModel: DropDownMenuViewModel
) {
    UserSignUpScreenInfo(
        username = "",
        navController,
        viewModel
    )
}

@Composable
fun UserSignUpScreenInfo(
    username: String,
    navController: NavController,
    ViewModel: DropDownMenuViewModel
) {
    // Saves the state of the textfield
    val textFieldUserName = remember { mutableStateOf(username) }

    // Creating a list of themes
    val themeColors = listOf("Original(Purple)","Blue", "Red", "Neutral", "Pink", "Yellow", "Green", "Orange")

    // Stores the selected theme
    var selectedTheme by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    var textFieldSize by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Size.Zero)
    }

    // Saves the state of the theme drop down menu
    var expandedTheme by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    // Icon for theme dropdown
    var icon = if(expandedTheme){
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp
    } else {
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown
    }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "User Account",
            modifier = Modifier
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Text(
            text = "User Account Name:",
        )
        Text(
            text = "This will be shown as the users' name only visible to the account",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp)
        )
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Transparent, shape = RoundedCornerShape(25))
                .padding(8.dp),
            placeholder = { Text(text =  "(i.e. Mandy)") },
            value = textFieldUserName.value,
            onValueChange = { textFieldUserName.value = it },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = selectedTheme,
            onValueChange = { selectedTheme = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    // This value is used to assign to
                    // the DropDown the same width
                    textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                },
            label = { Text(text = "Theme")},
            trailingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    icon,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { expandedTheme = !expandedTheme }
                )
            }
        )
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expandedTheme,
            onDismissRequest = { expandedTheme = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(with(LocalDensity.current){textFieldSize.width.toDp()})
        ) {
            themeColors.forEach { theme ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    selectedTheme = theme
                    expandedTheme = false
                }) {
                    Text(
                        text = theme,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Row(){
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    if(textFieldUserName.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                        ViewModel.addUserName(
                            UserNameUiState(
                                userName = textFieldUserName.value,
                            )
                        )
                        textFieldUserName.value = ""
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Add another user",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    if(textFieldUserName.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                        ViewModel.addUserName(
                            UserNameUiState(
                                userName = textFieldUserName.value,
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    ViewModel.setUserTheme(selectedTheme)
                    navController.navigate(DestinationScreens.HomePage.route)
                    Log.i("UserUIStateUpdate", ViewModel._userTheme.value)
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Next"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Theme kt. composable:

````
@Composable
fun DropDownMenuTheme(
  //  darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    theme: String,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    val colors = when(theme){
        "Blue" -> LightColorPaletteBlue
        "Red" -> LightColorPaletteRed
        "Neutral" -> LightColorPaletteNeutral
        "Pink" -> LightColorPalettePink
        "Yellow" -> LightColorPaletteYellow
        "Green" -> LightColorPaletteGreen
        "Orange" -> LightColorPaletteOrange
        else -> LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}```
````